# what is the meaning of error "Must declare the scalar variable @ " in .NET Core

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, dapper

I'm new to .NET Core; I tried to save image on wwwroot folder and saved file name name and path to the SQL Server database using Dapper

```
public async Task<string> WriteFile(IFormFile file)
{
        String fileName;

        try
        {
            var extension = "." + file.FileName.Split('.')[file.FileName.Split('.').Length - 1];
            fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + extension; 
            var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot\\s", fileName);

            using (var bits = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
            {
                await file.CopyToAsync(bits);
            }

            Image image = new Image(fileName,path);

            toDb(image);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return e.Message;
        }

        return fileName;
}

public void toDb(Image image)
{
        string fileName = image.fileName;
        string path = image.path;

        using (IDbConnection dbConnection = Connection)
        {
            string sQuery = "INSERT INTO images(title, dir)" + "VALUES(@fileName, @path)";

            dbConnection.Open();
            dbConnection.Execute(sQuery,image);
        }
    }
}
```

Is this way wrong or how can I fix this error with dapper?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Must declare the scalar variable "@UserName"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8933634/must-declare-the-scalar-variable-username)

Comment: thank you but still get same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are invoking the dapper command incorrectly.

The error happens as the executed command is unable to find the `@fileName,@path` parameters

You have to pass the parameter names using anonymous classes

Like

```
dbConnection.Execute(sQuery, new { fileName = filename, path = path });
```

Or

```
dbConnection.Execute(sQuery, new { fileName = image.fileName, path = image.path});
```

Reference [Dapper: Parameterized queries](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper#parameterized-queries)